# Magento 2 - How to remove cache files manually

Tags: magento2, cache

What are the cache directories of `Magento 2` ?

I just need to remove those with my `rm -rf` command, without executing Magento `cache:flush` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either u can manually delete folders or using this command

```
rm -rf var/cache/ generated/code pub/static/frontend pub/static/adminhtml
```

After that you need to run these commands again , else the css/styles in magento frot-end and back-end won't load

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Comment: After remove folder, need to run setup:upgrade! why ?

Answer (score 1):

So do you want to remove cache files ? If yes, then remove these folders:

> /var/cache
>
> /var/page_cache

Simply remove this folders.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove these directories

```
<magento_root>/var/cache/* 
<magento_root>/var/page_cache/* 
<magento_root>/generated/metadata/* 
<magento_root>/generated/code/*
```

for more information please follow this link:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/partial-caching/database-caching.html