# Magento2 - You have placed no orders

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order

After placing an order the Customer's Account shows

> You have placed no orders. and shopping carts and wish lists. it gone?

**Please Help**

[image]

Backend

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Check debug.log, system.log, exception.log. Are you getting any helpful information?

Comment: In database   table named  'sales_order_status_state' . Make sure its visible_on_frontend is valued 1

Comment: @MrZid Ok wait sir i will check and update ty

Comment: @MrZid Please check This  https://prnt.sc/r8tngb

Comment: @user55548 [2020-02-28 05:15:10] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://www.upgrademag.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?brand_for_product_detail=2643&cat=10&close_out=9&q=Combination+wrench+set","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

Comment: Open order from the backend and check the Customer Group. It shouldn't be NOT LOGGED IN.

Comment: @MrZid Yes Plz Check how did this happen  https://prnt.sc/r8tsmo

Comment: First log in and then place order. Not logged in user have not order list.

Comment: @MrZid  and my shopping carts and wish lists. it gone?

Comment: that might be some cache issue problem. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/305580/85429   try run these cammands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You may have ordered as a `NOT lOGGED IN` user
2. Check if `customer_id` is `NULL` in table `sales_order` for your corresponding order

In case if You have ordered after logged in, then your customer Id is not storing in the DB 
Then you need to try this

```
$data = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $data->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in the admin that the order has a status, and that that status is set to be visible in the table: sales_order_status_state

(I know this question has been answered and accepted, but had the same problem today, except that the orders created using a certain payment method did not have a status set, and hence did not display for the customer on the frontend.)

If that still doesn't solve the problem, I'd recommend looking at the getRecentOrders() function in Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent which does joining and filtering. Below for reference:

```
   private function getRecentOrders()
{
    $orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(
        '*'
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'customer_id',
        $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'store_id',
        $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'status',
        ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
    )->addAttributeToSort(
        'created_at',
        'desc'
    )->setPageSize(
        self::ORDER_LIMIT
    )->load();
    $this->setOrders($orders);
}
```